# How to find top N meanings in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

everyone 
I have a data frame like this:\

| mz | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 | 47 |
| 34 | 35 | 56 |
| 67 | 23 | 98 |
| 23 | 25 | 56 |
| 67 | 78 | 65 |
| 12 | 56 | 77 |
| 77 | 2 | 100 |

I want to find top 4 numbers from column "var1", and extract column "mz" meanings.
Result that I expect is following:

1, 34, 67, 12
or (even better)

| mz | var1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 |
| 34 | 35 |
| 67 | 78 |
| 12 | 56 |

I will be glad for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order`:

```r
result <- df[order(-df$var1),][1:4,-3]
result[order(rownames(result)),]
#>   mz var1
#> 1  1   56
#> 2 34   35
#> 5 67   78
#> 6 12   56
```